# How to use package:intl

Tags: dart

I want to use package:intl to make multi lang html page.
I have seen example/basic_example.dart but don't find document of message_lookup_by_library.dart, intl_helpers.

Is there a simple example use package:intl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of that are still work in progress, e.g. there should be an update so that plurals and genders work in the next few days. To see the basic workflow, take a look at the intl/test/message_extraction directory and specifically message_extraction_test.dart That does a round-trip extraction, translation, code generation, and running the result. The end result is roughly what you see in basic_example.dart, but it actually does the intermediate steps to produce that.

That test uses a trivial JSON format for output and the translations are hard-coded. You could manually translate things using that format, but for real usage you would probably want to use a real translation tool and a format that it understood. There is a little bit of documentation at http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/intl/Intl.html but for the time being you're probably stuck looking at the code and/or asking questions.